# could not save the file /usr/... permission denied (13.04)

Tags: 13.04, permissions, gedit, conky

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and am trying to create an .sh file for conky in `/usr/bin` using gedit.
When trying to save I get the error dialogue:

```
Could not save the file /usr/bin/conky-start.sh
You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again."
```

From searching, I think I have to run a command in terminal to allow permission, but I couldn't find out what that is.

**Edit:**
I'm trying to *create* the file conky-start.sh, not change or run it.
Thus far, I've opened gedit, copied and pasted some required info from the net, and I'm trying to save-as `/usr/bin/conky-start.sh`

Perhaps I need to create the file first in terminal, then edit it?

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/bin/conky-start.sh
```

Write the contents of the file and you should be able to save it. To make it executable, you may need to do:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/conky-start.sh
```

Comment: I wish y'all would make up your minds! This edit admonishes me to _use_ gksudo: askubuntu.com/questions/220048/ubuntu-12-04-wireless-wont-connect-with-gnome-network-manager-or-wicd/225161#225161

Comment: The file conky-start.sh doesn't exist yet. I'm trying to create it, not open it.

Comment: On my fully updated 13.04 system, I can create it with gksudo but not with pkexec.

Comment: Finally got it. I just did "gksudo gedit", and then I was able to save the file anywhere I wanted. Thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 2):

You have to become super user, by using sudo command.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the terminal
2. Type `sudo gedit /usr/bin/conky-start.sh`
3. It will ask for the password. Type the password. Now you ll be able to save the save without any problem.

Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo for more information on sudo.