# I am not able to access Root's home folder in Ubuntu

Tags: root

I'm using Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS, and I want to access root's home folder.

Comment: I know this is answered ...but can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish in root's home folder (`/root`)? It might be possible for an answer to be posted that addresses your needs specifically. Also, sometimes people confuse `/root` (root's home folder) with `/` (the root directory), which are "root" in an entirely different sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be root to access Root's home folder.

Comment: Thank you! But problem is solved.

Comment: @Chinmay, you must then click the check mark by the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: I have done that!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
sudo -i nautilus
```

?

Run it in the terminal or after pressing Alt+F2

Comment: [No `sudo` on nautilus please. Use `gksudo` instead](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Comment: [No `gksudo` on Ubuntu 13.04 and up. Use `pkexec` instead](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313828/why-is-pkexec-preferred-over-gksudo-for-graphical-applications) but note that this doesn't work well for X applications like nautilus.

Comment: I am using 12.04 and the above command works for me. You will notice the root folder icon has change to a folder with a house on it.

Comment: I tried "gksudo" command instead sudo. It worked.

Comment: For 13.04 you may want to take a look at this question:[Why is gksu no longer installed by default in 13.04?](http://askubuntu.com/q/284306/107450) and my advice would be to install gksu and configure the if necessary. But once installed `gksudo` is definitely easier. pkexec is not easy to use with graphical applications yet

Comment: ohh! okay! But I'm using ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS.