# Can sudo be reinstalled after being removed?

Tags: sudo, software-installation

This seems to be a chicken-egg problem.
The most common task using `sudo` is installing and removing software.

```
sudo apt-get purge <appname>
```

But `sudo` itself can be removed.

```
sudo apt-get purge sudo # Do not run this command on production computers!
```

This is where the fun comes

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

Although it's obvious that no person in his right mind will purge `sudo` (other than me), **someone can be fooled** to run this command (not directly, in its hex mode, or whatever it's called) or **a person could SSH in** disguised as tech guru **and do the mess**.

So is there a way of reinstalling sudo?

Comment: good one I never even knew sudo could purged too! linux is just so damn customisable!

Comment: Not really worth an answer, since it would be too late if this happened, but there is nothing *preventing* you setting a password for the `root` user. You can then use `su`, or log in directly as root if you have physical access to the machine (ssh will generally be configured to reject attempts to log in as root).

Comment: All answers do depend on some way of accessing the filesystem with privileges.  For (counter)example: my Android Asus Memopad does not have `sudo` and has no "safe boot" or equivalent.  The only way I know of is to go to `xda-dev` and d/l a prebuilt full install package.  You're lucky, so  to speak, that you don't have this limitation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Android is a linux derivative, than actually being a linux distro. Also google has made many changes in it(which most linux fans hate). **Rooting**, which is well known on android smartphone, is nothing but an attempt to gain the powers of **real linux** on android.

Comment: @AdityaPatil No argument - I just wanted to make sure people were aware of the difference but wrote too little.

Comment: Can't you just login as root?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I wasn't argumenting, I just extended your comment a little further.

Comment: Sure, just do `sudo apt-get install sudo`, oops too late :-)

Comment: If sudo was removed, then why would it be needed to reinstall it if Ubuntu is no longer aware of it?

Comment: Related: [How to modify an invalid '/etc/sudoers' file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I can install applications using:

```
pkexec apt-get install <appname>
```

From `man pkexec`:

> ```
>   pkexec allows an authorized user to execute PROGRAM as another user. If
>   username is not specified, then the program will be executed as the
>   administrative super user, root.
> ```

So, I suppose that `pkexec apt-get install sudo` should work as well.

---

**Edit**: now I can confirm: *yes*, `sudo` can be installed using using `pkexec  apt-get install sudo`:

[image: reinstall sudo]

<sup>([click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcPsw.png))</sup>

Comment: @RaduRadeanu This is interesting i am going to try this thanks u ......

Comment: @Premkumar Test it with precaution! The last command from the screen shoot should be probably in your case only: `sudo apt-get install gksu ubuntu-minimal`. But better, check which packages was removed in the same time with `sudo`.

Comment: could I theoretically `sudo apt-get purge pkexec`?

Comment: @Thebluefish No. Doesn't exist such a package called `pkexec`.

Comment: Ah good to know. Pretty new to Linux myself, and I didn't want to take the chance :p

Comment: @Thebluefish The package is called `policykit-1` (as of 12.04). It can be removed, but at the expense of removing packages that you'd usually want on a desktop system such as `gnome-core` and `ubuntu-desktop` (on a server, it's more likely not to be required by any necessary package). However, Radu, what determines that your account can use `pkexec apt-get …`? Is this something that you configured, or does it happen automatically, and if so, what determines that an account can do this?

Comment: @Gilles I don't remember to be made some configurations in this sense in the past. So, I suppose that is happen automatically. If you know what determines that an account can do this, please share; this is outside of my area of expertise.

Comment: @Gilles I *think* members of the `sudo` group can use `pkexec`. (My experience is that adding users to this group confers `pkexec` abilities and removing them from it removes `pkexec` abilities; in this way, `pkexec` abilities seem to be conferred the same was as `sudo` abilities in the default `sudoers` config, which makes sense since being able to `sudo` and `pkexec` as root are mainly what makes a user an administrator in Ubuntu.) I don't think uninstalling `sudo` will remove the `sudo` group. But *I am **not** totally sure my suppositions are true under all reasonable circumstances.*

Comment: I understand that `sudo` (with its relatives `gksudo` and `gksu`, which are not quite the same as each other despite what people will tell you) is being replaced by `pkexec`. I have read that `sudo` will not be present in future versions of Ubuntu, though I don't know if that is correct. When `pkexec` replaces `sudo`, I don't know what will replace `gksudo`.

Comment: @PaddyLandau I don't think that `sudo` will not exists in future versions of Ubuntu. Maybe you read about `gksudo`. See [Why is pkexec preferred over gksudo for graphical applications?](http://askubuntu.com/q/313828/147044)

Comment: i got `bash: pkexec: command not found` lol

Answer (score 29):

You can always boot into [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), drop to root shell and install it without sudo.

Comment: can you add the essential and relevant part from the link here?

Comment: If  there's no recovery available in the grub boot menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> and add ` single` to the bootline. Then, when booted, set a root password using `passwd`. Reboot normaly, on the commandline enter `su` followed by the new password, and run `apt-get install sudo` (without the `sudo`-prefix)

Comment: How did you get internet connection on root shell?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, reinstalling `sudo` package would be possible via **chroot** method.

- First boot from Ubuntu live disk.
- Mount the previously installed Ubuntu partition into whatever directory you want.In my case, i mounted it in `/media/ubuntu`.

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu
  sudo mount /dev/sdaX /media/ubuntu   # /dev/sdaX - previously installed Ubuntu partition.
  ```
- By default you didn't able to get internet connection after chrooted into a partition.So run the below command to make it work.

  ```
  for d in dev sys run proc; do sudo mount --bind /$d /media/ubuntu/$d ; done
  ```

<sub>Thanks to @Oli for [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14299145#14299145) wonderful piece of code .</sub>

- Now chroot into that mounted directory,

  ```
  $ sudo chroot /media/ubuntu
  # apt-get update
  ```
- Install `sudo` package by running,

  ```
  # apt-get install sudo
  ```
- Now exit out of chrooted environment.

  ```
  exit
  ```
- Finally boot up your Ubuntu OS.Now test your `sudo` command, it will surely works.

Answer (score 4):

Boot with the extra parameter `init=/bin/sh` on the kernel command line.  This will put you directly into a root shell, from where you can simply run `apt-get install sudo` and then reboot.  You may need to run `/etc/init.d/networking start` to get a working network connection first. Far simpler than messing around with recovery CDs or live disks, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

If you already set or update  the `root` user account password by this command `sudo passwd root` then you don't worry about purging `sudo`.Just login into your `root` account and then install `sudo`,

```
su
apt-get install sudo
```

[image]

<sub>[**Click here to enlarge**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP2UX.png)</sub>

Comment: this works if the root account is enabled, and on ubuntu it is usually disabled. `su` on my pc gives "su: Authentication failure", although I provided correct password

Comment: yes, you are correct that's what i said.If you already updated the root user account password then you don't worry about purging `sudo`.Now try this, `sudo passwd root`, it will allows you to update root user account password.Now relogin into your root account by running `su` command.Once you   able to login then you will be free to purge sudo.Now purge sudo by `sudo apt-get purge sudo`.Login into your root account to reinstall sudo package by running `su` and `apt-get install sudo`

Answer (score -1):

sudo (and any other root privilege) only applies to the running OS. If you have been silly and removed sudo (or /usr/ for that matter) and don't have alternates like pkexec you can simply boot from something else, copy the missing software, and restart again.

Physical access nullifies any and all software security your system may have.

Comment: I recommend expanding this to explain what you mean by "copy the existing software."

Comment: Not a very easy way to fix it though.

Comment: @Seth without op intervention I seriously doubt it could be fixed without writing another answer.

Comment: Well the proper way of doing that would be chroot, but there are so many less barbaric ways. For instance, logging in as root (the NORMAL way), or, if you somehow don't have root password, just set init=/bin/bash as kernel parameter, and you pass by the entire init system including the login authentication.

Answer (score -2):

This problem seems to be very ubuntu-specific. As non-ubuntu user I didn't even understand at first why sudo would be a special case in any way (a lot of distributions don't install it by default).

You don't need sudo at all. It's just a lazy shortcut that allows you to execute a root command without actually logging in as root. However, if you have to do anything more than a single command, it's just awful constantly prefixing everything with sudo. Not to mention that using `sudo` makes users ignorant about how permissions and root account work. It makes much more sense to just login as root, do the administration of the system and logout. That you do with `su` if you are already logged in as a regular user. Or you could log in directly as root.

Of course you need to have `root` password set, that's the reasonable configuration, otherwise you have a windows-like system where there are actions that nobody can perform and you are really locked out if somehow `sudo` isn't available (it requires working `/etc/`, set `$PATH` and other things mounted - which you may not have if something goes wrong early in boot).

Comment: This may be useful information, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Indeed. This really isn't that relevant to a system where root's password *is* disabled and sudo *is* installed by default. And if you look at the other answers, you'll see the last paragraph isn't true either.

Comment: A user that contemplates removing `sudo` from ubuntu should also consider setting the root password (other questions pointed out how to do that). A user that doesn't care about this stuff, can keep using sudo.