# sudo is not installed, both sudo and su are not working

Tags: 16.04, permissions, sudo, root, su

When trying to switch to root using sudo su :

```
Error- sudo is not installed
```

When trying to switch with `su` command:

```
Error- this program is not installed
```

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Results of `/usr/bin/sudo` :

```
 /usr/bin/sudo bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: please [edit] your question with the output of `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: Please help me bro !!

Comment: Can you open a terminal and enter `/usr/bin/sudo` and report what it says?

Comment: user@user-HP-Pro-3330-MT:/$ /usr/bin/sudo
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory

Comment: Either you're on a VPS that doesn't provide root access (except possibly through a management console) or you're removed the `sudo` package - in which case see [Can sudo be reinstalled after being removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434525/can-sudo-be-reinstalled-after-being-removed)

Comment: what to do now,please guide me

Comment: @DebashisPriyadarshi tell us if your server runs on your own physical server or if it is virtual .. and where it is hosted if virtual.

Comment: It is physical server

Comment: What's the output of `/bin/su`? If `su` is missing, I'd say the install is probably hosed in other respects as well... If su is available, it's basically a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password), and you can install sudo after setting root password.

Comment: In short, as @steeldriver wrote, try: `pkexec apt-get install sudo`

Comment: Thanks alot :) pkexec apt-get install sudo worked

Answer (score 2):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
pkexec apt install sudo
```

You can also test the above command by simulating it without installing anything:

```
pkexec apt install --simulate sudo
```