# Sudo vanished Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: apt, sudo, 18.10

Somehow I do not have sudo on my PC anymore, perhaps I may have uninstalled it somehow? I pasted this into my terminal earlier:

```
 sudo rm osbuddy sudo nano osbuddy
```

And now it seems sudo is not there anymore.

When I write sudo, the terminal outputs

```
Command 'sudo' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install sudo
```

Obviously this does not work since when I write `sudo apt install sudo`

The sudo command is not found of course.

```
If I just write apt install sudo
```

It says that I need to be root. What do I do?

Comment: `sudo rm osbuddy sudo nano osbuddy` means DELETE osbuddy AND sudo AND nano AND osbuddy. If you want to chain multiple commands, user a separator like `;` or `&&`

Comment: nano was not deleted though

Comment: was not in current path...

Comment: The best answer seems to be this: https://askubuntu.com/a/434530/69802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to repair:

Enter recovery mode:
Press & hold shift key while bios starts ([See more](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode))

Select Menu network
Will enable the network

Select Menu root
Will open a root shell

Type some commands:

```
dpkg-reconfigure sudo
apt install sudo
reboot
```

This should repair sudo