# How to log in to boot partition from live cd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, live-cd

I accidentally uninstall an important package, and need internet to reinstall it. I found it difficult to connect to mikrotik network via terminal, so maybe can i login into my boot partition from live cd. So i can login to mikrotik using UI in live cd and use the internet to download the missing package in my current boot partition.

Comment: How do you mean log in? You could add the CD to software sources and install the package from it, if it has it. This seems like a typical https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem to me. What package did you uninstall? And why is your internet not working without a live cd?

Comment: Those links may be helpful to you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: Perhaps you are asking how to re-install packages from a `chroot`? if so, see [Can sudo be reinstalled after being removed?](https://askubuntu.com/a/434531/178692)

Comment: it is because i avoid to connect to network using text mode

Comment: @steeldriver looks like your answer fits my question, ill look into it, and confirm soon