# Can't use sudo. wrong ELF class

Tags: 18.04, sudo, security

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Whenever I try to use `sudo`, I get:

```
[sudo] password for user: fingerprint-helper: error while loading shared libraries: libaudio.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

so I cannot use `sudo` any more as it says:

```
Sorry, try again.
```

when I type the password.

*How can I restore `sudo` access without access to `sudo`?*

**Note:** removing the fingerprint software is an option.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se].  **:-)** Did you install that file manually?  If not, remove the 32-bit version and install the 64-bit version of the package.

Comment: @Fabby Thank you but, I installed Fingerprint GUI manually and it worked for more then 2 weeks without any errors. Now I can't remove it because I can't use sudo anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is broken, `pkexec` may still work even though `sudo` doesn't. [Polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) (of which the [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) command [is a part](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/polkit.8.html)) and `sudo` are separate mechanisms in Ubuntu that allow administrators to perform actions as root.

I don't know how you installed the fingerprint software, so I don't know how to remove it. But whatever commands you would run with `sudo`, you can usually run with `pkexec` in place of `sudo`, at least as long as they're not commands that run graphical applications.

That is, instead of running:

```
sudo some-command...
```

Run:

```
pkexec some-command...
```

Ubuntu users have used `pkexec` to solve a variety of problems where they couldn't use `sudo`, including [`sudo` being uninstalled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434525/can-sudo-be-reinstalled-after-being-removed) and [`sudo` being misconfigured](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file). But depending on what is broken, it's possible that running `pkexec` will fail as well; I'm not sure that can be ascertained from the information you've provided (so if it works for you it might not work for people who find this question by searching, or vice versa).

If you *are* able to run commands as root with `pkexec` but uninstalling the fingerprint software doesn't fix the problem, the next step would be to look into the file whose name is mentioned in the error message, `libaudio.so.2`. This file is provided by [the `libaudio2` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libaudio.so.2&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any). So if you can run commands as root with `pkexec`, you can attempt to reinstall that package:

```
pkexec apt install --reinstall libaudio2
```

I can't really give any more specific advice than that based on the information available so far. But I can give more *general* advice: to find official Ubuntu packages that provide a particular file, go to [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com) and search under where it says "Search the contents of packages." (I mention this for the benefit of others who find this question by searching, but also for you, in case you get additional errors messages after fixing the one you've seen so far.)

Comment: Huh! Didn't think of that...  **+1**  I was going to close as dupe if my answer helped.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Just [drop to a root shell prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) and uninstall the fingerprint software from there the same way you installed it.

Then reboot and log on normally and `sudo` will be back.