# sudo apt-get dist-upgrade removed sudo and other programs

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I was following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04) guide on upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, and after executing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, I did not bother to check that it prompted me that executing it will remove lots of programs. After `dist-upgrade`, I noticed that I do not have `sudo` anymore. I tried installing via `install` but I get an error that looks like this:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

How can I recover from this?

Comment: So basically you are in the same situation as this --> [Can sudo be reinstalled after being removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434525/can-sudo-be-reinstalled-after-being-removed)

Comment: @steeldriver I'm in a worse situation I think, ```pkexec``` is not installed and I have to install ```policykit-1```. Running ```apt-install policykit-1``` results in the error message I posted.

Comment: Probably safer to reinstall whole system, since you don't know what other programs are messed up.

Comment: @Daniel that seems to be the only thing to do in this situation...

Comment: Had you enabled root login?  By default it's disabled, but if you've enabled it, login as root so you don't have to use `sudo`.

Comment: Related (but *not* a duplicate): [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/q/28099) shows how to chroot from a live environment to use an installed system's package manager. [Andrea Corbellini's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/249373) to [Ubuntu system is broken after accidentally uninstalling many packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/249367) shows how to install potentially many missing packages even if you're not sure what packages they are (or see [Where are the logs for apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/q/425809)) You shouldn't *need* to reinstall.