# Command sudo not found, even though it is installed

Tags: sudo

This happened to me after installing java. I believe I messed with the ./bashrc file if I'm correct.

I've checked my files and sudo is still there, but ubuntu seems to not be able to find it.

Before installing java I could use sudo.

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` and `which sudo` show?

Comment: echo $PATH is the default path, but which sudo is empty

Comment: sudo should be in /usr/bin; if `which` doesn't see it, then your path is definitely not the default. Please post your path, along with any entry in ~/.bashrc that references it.

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: In my bashrc file theres no mention of path besides in a comment, and no literal mention of the string /usr/local/....

Comment: OK - try running, as a test, `/usr/bin/sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Odd, it says no such file or directory, but I dont remember deleting the file.

Comment: At least we're getting somewhere. Can you confirm that `sudo` is still installed?

Comment: How would I do that, doing apt install sudo tells me it's already installed to version 1.8.21p2

Comment: Maybe it just got deleted by mistake. Can you switch to the root account via `su -`? If so, try reinstalling sudo - `sudo apt-get install --reinstall sudo`.

Comment: I'm in the root from safe boot, running apt-get install --reinstall sudo shows up it says reinstalled 1 but also Err: could not resolve us.archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: Which sudo is also empty still.

Comment: This is not good. Try `locate sudo`; if that doesn't find it, try `find / -name sudo`.

Comment: Locate sudo printed out about 20 or 30 lines of usr/ and var/

Comment: Instead of rebooting into safe-boot, can you get to a root console via `su -`?

Comment: In order for me to get Into su - I have to use a password,  and using the only password I've given the computer doesnt work, while in order to change it I need sudo I believe.

Comment: If reinstalling from safe-boot didn't work (I'm assuming because of the network issue), the only other thing I can think of is to download the sudo package, reboot into safe-boot, purge sudo, then reinstall it from the deb - `dpkg -i /path/to/sudo-deb`.

Comment: No such file or directory. Would plugging an ethernet cable let me connect to the internet to install?  If not I'll download the package and try the dpkg

Comment: Just download the package - no need to waste anymore of your time.

Comment: Related: [Can sudo be reinstalled after being removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434525/can-sudo-be-reinstalled-after-being-removed)

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall sudo:

```
pkexec apt-get install --reinstall sudo
```