# Command 'sudo' not found

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, dpkg, sudo

I tried to install sudo with `apt install sudo` but it won't work. I got these errors:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)  
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I am always required to give root access whenever i want to open some files in the terminal but i can't do that without sudo

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using? sudo most of the times is pre-installed. Did you purge/uninstall that? What is the output of `type -a sudo`?

Comment: @Kulfy, isn't `sudo` installled *all* the time?  How would you get root access and privileges without it?

Comment: You need to install sudo in debian. In ubuntu, it's already packaged.
Here, you get the normal output of `apt install` run without sudo.

Insteed, try `sudo apt install cowsay`. Sudo gives the root rights temporarely so you can install cowsay. Without sudo, you can't install any package

Comment: `sudo` is always packaged with Ubuntu, and according to my experience, also in current versions of Debian, but there are Linux distros, where it is not packaged with the default installations. - But you might remove it by mistake, and that would cause problems in Ubuntu. I guess you can boot in recovery mode (and run as root), and then install `sudo'.

Comment: @Kulfy I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I was able to use sudo when i started using Ubuntu, but unluckily for me it stopped working

Comment: @Ollie If you use Ubuntu in a Docker container, the `root` account is the default one. And yes `sudo` isn't installed there.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot, go to grub menu and select recovery boot.

Then select root console. Run there

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt install sudo
```

Comment: `pkexec` may also work :)

Comment: @Kulfy I don't remember how to use it. So you can write another answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 [Radu Rădeanu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/434530/816190) on the linked question pretty explains this.