# How to prompt for sudo password using GUI?

Tags: bash, python, scripts, password, sudo

I have written a Python script that executes several sudo-requiring actions.

How can I make the script provide a GUI prompt for the `sudo` password when executed?

I've tried placing `gksudo -s python file.py` into a bash script - running it so that it executes the above command; but that doesn't work, unfortunately...

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ? see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/515292/how-to-get-gui-sudo-password-prompt-without-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this inside your script 'file.py', running as normal user :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['gksudo', 'your first sudo action here'])
subprocess.call(['gksudo', 'another bash command'])
```

or this inside a parent python script

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['gksudo','python file.py'])
```