# "Command 'gksu' not found" error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gksu, gksudo

While running

```
gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/somefile.rules
```

I am getting this suggestion.

```
Command 'gksu' not found, did you mean:

  command 'gosu' from deb gosu
  command 'ksu' from deb heimdal-clients
  command 'ksu' from deb krb5-user

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`gksu` has been deprecated.

It's been removed from Ubuntu 18.04, as well as Debian and other newer Linux distributions. If you do a web search with the phrase "Ubuntu man gksu", you will see there's no 18.04 version available. Here are alternatives:

1. Use `sudo -H`:

   ```
   sudo -H nautilus
   ```
2. Use `admin://`:

   ```
   gedit admin:///etc/udev/rules.d/somefile.rules
   ```
3. Use `pkexec`:

   ```
   pkexec gedit
   ```

Comment: Don't think just `pkexec gedit` would work without any system modification first. You'll most likely get 'connection refused' error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and edit. @pomsky

Comment: If only for gedit, I personally prefer `VISUAL=gedit sudoedit /etc/fstab`

Comment: What is the difference between alternatives?