# How GUI based apps ask for root password without gksudo installed?

Tags: sudo, gksudo

In old ubuntu releases, I believe, GUI apps ask for root password using **gksudo**. Now `gksudo` not comes preinstalled in ubuntu. For me, if I am adding a custom launcher of a compiled executable which needs to be run as root, I need to install `gksudo` and add `gksudo -k -u root`, followed by the execution command. But in certain apps, like Synaptic Package Manager, Unetbootin ect, (which is installed via apt) can ask root password through GUI environment similar to good old `gksudo`. Actually How its being possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ssta properly mentioned there is something known as `pkexec` which is part of `policykit-1` package. You can verify that it is installed with `dpkg --get-selections | grep policy` . However, it doesn't necessarily mean it has a GUI front-end. The GUI front end is provided by another package - `policykit-1-gnome` for Unity and Gnome. For other desktop environments there are additional packages that provide GUI for their respective environment.

For more info on this tool refer to

[Why is pkexec preferred over gksudo for graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/313828/295286)

[When to use pkexec vs. gksu/gksudo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/78352/295286)

Answer (score 3):

I believe we're now supposed to use:

`pkexec <command>`